# How to avoid NetworkOnMainThreadException in this case?

Tags: kotlin

I have a function:

```
        fun getUpdatedStr(): DoubleArray {
            var Strings : DoubleArray = doubleArrayOf()
            for (i in 0..9) {
                val page = Jsoup.connect("somesite.com").get()
                val table = page.select("table").first().select("td").first()
                Strings += table.text()
                }
            return Strings
        }
```

That throws an **android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException**. My problem is that if I try to put this function into a Thread then I can't return the value to use it for other functions. What's the best way to work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot make a network call on Android from the main thread. You must use a worker thread.

This can be done in plain old Java thread, or some "higher level" constructs such as AsyncTask, HandlerThread, RxJava, coroutines etc.

Normally you can't "return" from a thread like you are looking for, as the execution would continue on the main thread after triggering the new one.
If you use coroutines, you can do this with suspend functions.

If you don't want to learn coroutines, with RxJava you'd have to return an observable to the calling functions

Otherwise, convert your method to callback based, and invoke the callback when you're finished

Comment: That was my question, whenever I try to use either of those I can't return the value from my function.

Comment: Added to my answer. Sorry, I saw that last part after answering it lol